# MS SQL server to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This query helps me to returns the previous month by having the actual month as parameter.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '01-'+'2014-05') - 1, 0), 105),4,10)
```

for example, here the query returns : '04-2014'

so how can i do the samething in postgresql, taking into account that postgresql doesn't use :

DATEDIFF , DATEADD functions?

Comment: refer [datediff of postgresql](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) and [dateadd of postgresql](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd)

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_char()` and `to_date()`:

```
select to_char(to_date('2014-05' || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '1 month', 'MM-YYYY')
```

I would encourage you to use the format "YYYY-MM" instead of "MM-YYYY", if you have a choice.  Putting the year first makes it possible to order by the value.